# How can I make my Data Service unit testable in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

Here is my solution folder:

[image]

I am using Entity Framework as ORM for my database and I also applied the unit of work pattern filled up with repositories for each of my entities. Project references are as follows:

**WebApi -> BusinessServices**

**WebApi -> BusinessEntities**

**BusinessServices -> DataModel**

**BusinessServices -> BusinessEntities**

The class that I want to test is my **DataService.cs** class that looks like this:

```
public class DataService : IDataService
    {
        private readonly LikkleUoW _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public DataService()
        {
            _unitOfWork = new LikkleUoW();
            var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.AddProfile<EntitiesMappingProfile>();
            });
            _mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        }
//Interface methods implementation
    }
```

This class is located in the **BusinessServices** project. And it is then used in my Web api controllers. What I want to do is to isolate it somehow from the 'new'-s in the constructor, make it injectable and test it. I have DI configured in my Web api project but I have the feeling my classes are not implemented really well. Currently my unit of work has DbContext as a property and passes it to all of the repositories. So, I created interface which my ow db context implements. After that I created fake db context which doesn't use real db but in memory containers. Maybe the information is not enough but the code is big and I would like an advice how to approach this situation.

The way I currently see it, I would have DataService mocked but somehow I want to be able to mock the unit of work which is being passed to its constructor so instead of using real database I would like it to use my FakeDbContext that uses fake db sets.

Comment: abstract the unit of work and inject that into data service. There is currently not enough info in provided example to give more detailed suggestion

Comment: I tried this approach, I extracted IUnitOfWork interface but inside of it I have IMyDbContext which is the interface that my db context implements. So the question was how to inject this from the different projects. If used via the Web api I want it to inject MyDbContext(located in DataModel proj.) where the interface is used, if used via the test project I want it to inject FakeDbContext which is also there but I don't want my Web api to directly reference my DataModel project.